# Exceptions to pausal form

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pentateuch-chumash, trop-cantillation, chumash

The pasuq reads, (Vayiqra 3:14)

ג,יד וְהִקְרִ֤יב מִמֶּ֨נּוּ֙ קָרְבָּנ֔וֹ אִשֶּׁ֖ה לַֽיהוָ֑ה אֶת־הַחֵ֨לֶב֙ הַֽמְכַסֶּ֣ה אֶת־הַקֶּ֔רֶב וְאֵת֙ כָּל־הַחֵ֔לֶב אֲשֶׁ֖ר עַל־**הַקֶּֽרֶב**׃

Why does the segol of the qof of the qerev at the end of the pasuq not turn into a qamets? Is this an exception to the concept of pausal forms, or is there a reason why this is was not done here.

Comment: See also 3:3, 3:9, 4:8, 7:3

Comment: Fascinating that they are all the same word -- qerev. Are there any other words which are exceptional?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98106/759